# Several stored procedure problems

Tags: sql, sql-server

I just started working with stored procedures. I have 2 problems.

When I create an object with a new name, it works successfully BUT no table shows up... where is it?

Second when I execute again I get an error

> There is already an object named '##sp_MemberCertificates' in the database

I'm trying to fix this by using:

```
IF (SELECT object_id('TempDB..##Temp')) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE ##Temp
END
```

But I don't know how to use this exactly...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ##sp_MemberCertificates (@MemberId int, @FromDate Varchar (30), @ToDate Varchar (30))
    AS
    SELECT  Email,
            CertificateNumber,
            Mem_Name,
            Mem_Address,
            Mem_city,
            Mem_state,
            Mem_cellno,
            Amount,
            DateValid,
            DateSent
    --Use INTO ?? --
    FROM UnitedDiningClub.dbo.UDC_Certificates

    JOIN UnitedDiningClub.dbo.UDC_Member m
    ON m.Mem_ID = UDC_Certificates.MemberId
    JOIN UnitedDiningClub.dbo.UDClub_Client c
    ON c.ClientId = UDC_Certificates.RestaurantId

    WHERE MemberId = @MemberId
    ORDER BY MemberId

    EXEC ##sp_MemberCertificates @MemberId = '1', @FromDate = '2011-07-19 00:00:00.000', @ToDate = '2015-07-19 00:00:00.000'

    go
```

Thanks for the help, please let me know if there more problems with the code, I am trying to learn.

Comment: Are you *really* intending to create a temporary stored procedure (please see [Temporary procedures : T-SQL](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jamie_thomson/archive/2009/11/25/temporary-procedures-sql-server.aspx))? Once you  have created an SP, you need to use [ALTER PROCEDURE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189762%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) to modify it. Also, you should not use `sp_` as a prefix to your SPs as SQL Server uses that for its own purposes; ref: [Avoid using sp_ as a prefix for stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Be very careful here. You are creating a temporary procedure. And, you are calling the procedure from inside. You are going to run into max recursion errors the first time you run this.

Comment: Can I just ask why you need to create a global temporary stored procedure?  What's the back-story here? Business requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this to execute your stored procedure

rename your procedure to **usp_MemberCertificates**  '##sp_MemberCertificates' is used for temp sp

remove exec statement from your procedure

use exec statement like this

`EXEC usp_MemberCertificates 1, '2011-07-19 00:00:00.000', '2015-07-19 00:00:00.000'`

you don't have to mention the variable name

moreover 1 is integer whereas you were sending a varchar type

also once you create a procedure you should add Alter instead of Create to so that it doesnt throw this error

> There is already an object named '##sp_MemberCertificates' in the
>   database

Comment: You should not use `sp_` as a prefix to stored procedures. Please see my earlier comment for the reference.

Comment: I know we should use usp_ as prefix but I am just trying to point out his errors, not his naming convention

Comment: You shouldn't really being using Hungarian notation (in SQL Server) at all: [What is the benefit of not using Hungarian notation?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/102689/what-is-the-benefit-of-not-using-hungarian-notation); many more opinions at [a google search](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=hungarian+notation+in+t-sql). The SP in question should probably be named `GetMemberCertificates`.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/55664ba0-e68b-429e-9a05-b40d5c5e790f/user-stored-procedure-naming-convention or http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/169/naming-conventions-for-sql-server-stored-procedures/

Comment: *I* think the general consensus of that article agrees with me. But then I will have [confirmation bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_bias), as will you. A few more samples of opinion would be useful :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, I will use usp_

Comment: Also thanks to @AndrewMorton for the correct naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

You create global temporary stored procedure (using prefix ##). This stored procedure is visible from all the sessions in the server. The stored procedure is in Temp DB (as you already mentioned). So you can add `DROP PROCEDURE`, not drop table as in your example. Also you have to `DROP` `##sp_MemberCertificates`, not `##Temp`.

Second when creating procedure the script must finish with `GO`, but before you try to execute (`EXEC ##sp_MemberCertificates @MemberId = '1', @FromDate = '2011-07-19 00:00:00.000'` in your code). Also if you intend to use `INTO` (`--Use INTO ?? --` in your code) you must drop table before that.